# How does installing app from google play on my PC works (network wise)?

Tags: android, google-play

I am a sofware developper having some network programming experience. I got pretty stunned when browsing the web on my PC, I ended up on google play with an app and an "install" button? What? No way a Web application can install an app on my cellular sitting on the desk ? But damn it works ?

Worse, I just tried it at the office, with surely other android devices around, and it worked again?

How can a PC link to a WiFi network makes its way to my android phone ?

I have a Moto G, my carrier is Virgin, however there is a strange Bell Canada popup with my phone id during install ?

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: When you hit install, all it's doing is telling Google to send a push notification to your phone to do an install. Your PC never sends anything to your phone.

Comment: You're logged in to your google account. Log out and then see how it doesn't work anymore

Comment: Also; this isn't really a development question

Comment: Couldn't find anything on the net about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android requires you to have a gmail account. The Google Play app on your phone synchronizes the device information with your gmail account on Google servers. When you browse Google Play on your desktop and you are logged into the same gmail account, it can identify the apps you have downloaded through Google Play and those that are available. It will also know your device and its compatibility.

When you hit "install" Google simply mimics pressing the "Install" button that is present when you are browsing Google Play apps on your device, and signal it to install the app.

It is not "WiFi" that makes it possible, but the Google Play app and the gmail account connection.